# openstack deployment (case studies)

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I want some case studies or different production environments in which openstack has been deployed. There are few questions here.

1- How do I decide that which components should go on the same node?
2- Which components would be able to interact directly ?
3- Which services need high availability?
4- What are the options for high availability ?
5 Are there any documentations for the deployed environments ? In which its explained why they used such approach how di it helped them and what are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the guides given at docs.openstack.org.
Especially

- Cloud Administrator Guide
- High Availability Guide
- Operations Guide
- Architecture Design Guide
- Networking Guide

You can start from Operations Guide.